# How do I access an object in another windows form using c#?

Tags: c#

I've got my windows form Main.cs and and my windows form Options.cs. Inside my Main.cs I've defined a class called "Player" and I've instantiated it there.

From my Options form I'd like to be able to access the methods and properties of the Player object I created in the Main.cs form. Visual Studio 2010 tells me "The name "Player1" does not exist in the current context.

What I think is weird and what is adding to my confusion is the fact that I can "see" static methods for my Player class from the Options.cs form.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

Inside Main.cs:

```
Player Player1 = new Player("Player 1", "X");
Player Player2 = new Player("Player 2", "O");
```

...

```
public class Player
{
    public static bool Turn { get; set; }
    public static int TotalGames { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }

    public static void ToggleTurn()
    {
        Turn = !Turn;
    }

    public Player(string name, string icon)
    {
        Name = name;
        Icon = icon;
    }

}
```

Inside Options.cs:

```
private void Options_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetCheckboxesToPlayerTurn();
    txtPlayer1Name.Text = Player1.Name; //HERE IS WHAT I WANT :(
}
```

Comment: Could you post a code sample? It would be easier to break the problem down with a short but representative program.

Comment: Done! I commented the line with what I was trying to do. On the options form, I'd like to have the textbox txtPlayer1Name.Text be set to the value from Name from the Player1 Object.

Comment: for accessing your Player Class properties, you need create an instance of that class, and for static properties there's no need to create an instance

Comment: Are `Player1` and `Player2` fields, or local variables in a method? If the former, you could change their visibilities to internal / public, or better still, create internal / public properties for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to somehow get a reference to your Player object from the Options form.

Change this line:

```
Player Player1 = new Player("Player 1", "X");
```

to

```
public Player Player1 = new Player("Player 1", "X");
```

and move it outside of the constructor (if that's where it is).
Then create a constructor in Options which accepts an instance of the Main, like this:

```
private Main main;
public Options(Main main)
{
  this.main=main;
}
```

Now, instead of creating Options with it's default constructor from Main, use(still in Main):

```
Options o = new Options(this);
```

You should now be able to reference your Players from Options using:

```
string name = this.main.Player1.Name
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static bool Turn { get; set; }
```

Means that this variable is SHARED between ALL instances of the class. So your turn logic wont work, as they share this variable.

> Visual Studio 2010 tells me "The name
>   "Player1" does not exist in the
>   current context.

Because you declare that variable in your main.cs, something that `Options.cs` has no access too. You would need to make the static variables, and then access those. IE

```
public static Player Player1;
public static Player Player2;
public static main(){
    Player1 = new Player("Player 1", "X");
    Player2 = new Player("Player 2", "O");
    ...
}
```

Comment: I kinda think making everything static is cheating :)

Comment: Ohh yes. But it is a simple game, and refactoring can come when it is working :)

Comment: Static reference is fine to get it working, but it's probably a bad habit to get into - I assume this is a practice application so we should try to apply good practices.  Your answer does answer the question anyway :)

Comment: @fosterz The asker shouldn't even be instanciating players in the main file, that logic belongs elsewhere. Ie a GameInstance. So the code is fundamentally flawed in its design. But this is a support forum to help people with their immediate problems, not spend several hours every time teaching them correct software design.

Answer (score 0):

use repository pattern for getting/creating players, 
identity map pattern for storing living references to playres
 and service locator pattern perhaps in a singleton instance for global access to your identity mapper(s).

for games global static is fine i think but...